# Why does the Condition Element in AWS API Gateway Resource Policy not trigger?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to understand how the Condition Element in Resource Policies for AWS API-Gateway triggers.

I've tried using SourceIP to block all traffic by allowing only 128.0.0.0/1 and 0.0.0.0/1 but I was able to hit my API from the same IP both times. I've also tried blocking my API with CurrentTime. But nothing I add to my condition seems to stop my ability to call my API. What am I misunderstanding?

My current attempt to block my API from all calls is this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:root"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:<AccountID>:<API>/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "DateGreaterThan": {
                    "aws:CurrentTime": "2019-12-15T12:00:00Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

From my understanding, by stating "DateGreaterThan" "CurrentTime" to December 2019 when it is currently September 2019, this API should not be callable for another three months.

Can someone show me where I'm going off track?

Thank you in advance!

PS: I have correct authorization in the body using AWS PublicKey/SecretKey. I'm just looking to block my call with the condition currently.

PPS: I forgot to mention that I've confirmed my API deployment is utilizing this Resource Policy as my API was rejecting calls before I added my AWS PublicKey/SecreyKey. (I enabled AWS_IAM Authorization)

As Joey Kilpatrick requested, here is my updated (still ineffectual) Resource Policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:user/Service_Account"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:<AccountID>:<API>/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, i'm hitting the API with a 147.x.x.x IP so I would expect this API to return a 403. I have also tested with the previously stated "CurrentTime" Condition.

Answer (score 1):

I want to first note that restricting SourceIP to 128.0.0.0/1 and 0.0.0.0/1 denies no IP address because every IP is in one of those two CIDR blocks.

But this is not your biggest problem: you cannot restrict any permissions from your `root` user. This is by design. See why it is a bad idea to use `root` user [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html).

Comment: I've created a service account with only Invoke permissions for API Gateway and retried with this account with blocking based on time, blocking 128.0.0.0/1 >>or<< 0.0.0.0/1 and I'm still able to hit my API. So there must be something else I'm missing.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the new policy? I’m confused about how you did the SourceIP.